# Viewing the Contents of "sysdiag" File

Tags: linux

I have been given a `sysdiag` file to analyse.

Is there a Linux command or programme that I can run to view the contents of this file?

Answer (score 1):

sysdiag is a small utility that enables for checking of system diagnostics.
to view the contents of this file you can try and open it using "gedit" text editor ,nano or vi.